# Invoke sbatch using R

Tags: r, system, slurm, sbatch, system2

How can I control the execution of **sbatch** from R?

I have an object called `baby.bash`, that holds the indications to execute a task in a remote computer. 
Then, by opening my terminal and executing the command line `sbatch baby.bash`, a task is triggered. When running the command line `sbatch baby.bash` in my terminal, the work executes correctly.

`baby.bash` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=WORKNAME
#SBATCH --mail-user=MYMAIL@A1.A2
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=34gb
#SBATCH --time=80:00:00
#SBATCH --output=o.out
#SBATCH --error=e.error

echo "stage 01"
renumf90 baby.par
echo "stage 02"
gibbsf90+ renf90.par --samples 500000 --burnin 10000 --interval 5
echo "stage 03"
echo -e renf90.par '\n' 0 '\n' 5 '\n' 0 | postgibbsf90
```

Nowadays, I am trying with `system()` and `system2()` functions.

Example 1: will return the current working directory

```
system2(command = 'pwd')
```

Example 2: will list folders and files in the current working directory.

```
system2(command = 'ls', arg = '-l')
```

Now, I want to execute the command **sbatch**, and parse as argument `baby.bsh`.

Buggy line 1:

```
system2(command = 'sbatch', arg = 'baby.bsh')
```

*sbatch: error: Invalid user for SlurmUser slurm, ignored*

*sbatch: fatal: Unable to process configuration file*

Buggy line 2:

```
system('sbatch baby.bsh')
```

*sbatch: error: Invalid user for SlurmUser slurm, ignored*

*sbatch: fatal: Unable to process configuration file*

It may sound trivial my willingness of execute `sbatch baby.bash` through R. The reasons I want to do this, is because in that way I could insert the execution line inside a R loop, and use my R skills to handle parallel works in my remote computer.

I am new in this world of COMPSCI and multicored computing, so please excuse me if I am misusing some terminology, or if my question is not relevant/clear.

Thanks and best

Comment: does `sbatch baby.bsh` work if you execute it from the command line/a shell? (Can we see the contents of `baby.bsh`?) (You might be interested in the [crew package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=crew) and the [future package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=future), both of which have tools for interacting with HPC systems ...)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your R setup on the cluster? For example, what modules do you load on the cluster. What you describe should work (`sbatch` via `system2()` in R works for me).